# why do I have to reference the method instead of the @variable?

Tags: ruby

Learning about classes, methods, global, instance variables and class variables.

Making a very basic account class, and the withdraw method takes 2 variables: pin_number, amount. I don't understand why both of these don't return true.

in the withdraw method if I go:

```
 if pin_number == pin
```

calls pin method returns @pin and statement is true

```
 if pin_number == @pin
```

statement returns false

my first assumption was the private tag, but I removed it and still doesn't return true.

```
class Account
  attr_reader :name, :balance
  def initialize(name, balance=100)
    @name = name
    @balance = balance
  end

  public
    def withdraw(pin_number, amount)
      if pin_number == pin
        @balance -= amount
        puts "Withdrew #{amount}. New balance: $#{@balance}."
      else
        puts pin_error
      end
    end

    def display_balance(pin_number)
      if pin_number == pin
        puts "Balance: $#{@balance}."
      else
        puts pin_error 
      end
    end

    def deposit(amt)
      @balance += amt
      puts @balance
    end
private
    def pin
    @pin = '1234'
  end

 def pin_error
    "Access denied: incorrect PIN."
  end
end

checking_account = Account.new('Jensen', 904)
checking_account.deposit(5)
checking_account.withdraw('1234',900)
```

Answer (score 3):

The effect you are seeing is because you only assign the instance variable `@pin` inside the `pin` method.

That is, it wasn't until you called `pin` in your comparison, that it got set. When you tried to use `@pin` directly, it had not yet been initialized.

Assign the `@pin` variable in `initialize` and then things will work.

```
class Account
  attr_reader :name, :balance
  def initialize(name, balance=100)
    @name = name
    @balance = balance
    @pin = '1234'
  end

  public
    def withdraw(pin_number, amount)
      if pin_number == @pin
        @balance -= amount
        puts "Withdrew #{amount} from pin #{@pin}, new bal is #@balance"
      else
        puts pin_error
      end
    end

    def display_balance(pin_number)
      if pin_number == @pin
        puts "Balance: $#{@balance}."
      else
        puts pin_error 
      end
    end

    def deposit(amt)
      @balance += amt
      puts "Deposited #{amt} to pin #@pin, new bal is #@balance"
    end

 def pin_error
    "Access denied: incorrect PIN."
  end
end

checking_account = Account.new('Jensen', 904)
checking_account.deposit(5)
checking_account.withdraw('1234',900)
```

This produces

```
Deposited 5 to pin 1234, new bal is 909
Withdrew 900 from pin 1234, new bal is 9
```